# How might a dragon escape from these advanced humans?

Tags: humans, dragons, space-constructs, prison, escape

**THE DRAGONS**

When standing on all fours, a typical full-grown dragon is about 3 times as tall as a human. They are quadrupedal with four legs, opposable thumbs on the front legs, and two or four wings, and can reasonably be expected to remain in the air for at least several hours at a time (and that's the low limit for sick or malnourished dragons). They are warm-blooded despite being reptiles, though they are slightly more vulnerable to being influenced by temperatures than humans (for example, a dragon in extremely cold conditions may become more sluggish, but not to the point that they can't function). They are broken up into a slew of sub-species, all of which share the above traits.

Some dragon species can breathe fire, but no dragon sub-species have inherent fire resistance. There are a few other 'inherent' abilities like ice breath, a venomous tail stinger, breathing underwater, and silk-weaving. Also, some of them have 'superpowers' of sorts that are not normal for their sub-species due to circumstances of birth or genetics, such as super-hot scales, mind-reading, future sight, or the ability to communicate with plants and accelerate their growth.

By some fluke of convergent evolution, they ended up as social creatures with emotions, thought patterns, and psychologies nearly identical to humans despite having started at the top of the food chain rather than the middle.

They do know that some humans exist on the planet with them, but in their minds, humans are prey creatures noteworthy for making little metal daggers and wood/stone dens for themselves. They are technologically and socially behind the dragons, and the dragons have absolutely no clue that other, crazy-advanced humans are hanging around up in orbit. The realization that there are humans up on a metal palace in the heavens who have unlocked the esoteric secrets of trapping and harnessing lightning, traversing sections of the sky where the air is thin enough to cause a dragon to suffocate, and giving traits from one creature to another is going to come as a big shock to the dragons.

**THE HUMANS**

The humans abandoned earth in favor of a space station in earth's orbit for a time due to an incoming extinction event, and the dragons evolved and took the humans' place in the grand scheme of things while they were gone. During this time, the general difficulties of space forced them to revert to an authoritarian government. They've begun to scout out the earth to see if it's habitable or not. They are still up on their space station, and have not revealed their existence to any humans or dragons on earth yet.

Human technology stagnated during their time in space due to resource-conservation measures, but still managed to reach near-futuristic levels. They have reliable spacecraft (that are sadly not capable of FTL travel), holographic projectors that can be paired with motion sensors for a 3D interface or used to cloak a ship from view, tiny chip-like implants that can monitor vitals and brain activity, several dozen 30-foot tall mecha similar in appearance to Fortnite's B.R.U.T.E.s that can outclass a typical dragon in raw strength, and experimental Directed Energy Weapons that are actually fairly practical as weapons if a tad unreliable. However, they still walk around, mainly use weapons that utilize bullets as ammo, and are reliant on hydroponic gardens for food and mining ice off the moon for water. They haven't changed much, aside from limited forays into genetic engineering; they have yet to figure out how to make entirely new DNA, but they can 'map' known DNA patterns from one organism onto another organism OF THE SAME SPECIES, which allows them to cure genetic disorders.

Note that the humans are capable of communicating with the dragons through a 'translation device', despite the fact that neither of them is capable of speaking the other's language, but as a general rule they don't bother communicating.

The humans have a pretty distinct technological advantage over the dragons, but the dragon's abilities might tip the power balance back in the dragon's favor, and the humans are aware of this. And this is added to by the fact that there is only a quarter as many humans up on the station as there are dragons down on the surface.

**THE SITUATION**

The dragons quickly perked the human's interest. For one, they are, much like bees, able to fly despite the fact that conventional physics tells them that their wings wouldn't allow them to. Plus, they'd really like to figure out how to get some of the dragon's abilities (anyone in favor of getting Telepathy?).

Now, to get these abilities, they need to map dragon genes onto their own genome, and to figure out how to do that do that, they need to do some experimentation. And the human in charge concluded that the most efficient way of going about that is to kidnap live dragons seemingly at random from the planet alien-abduction style, bring them up to their space station, and subject them to horrifically inhumane medical experiments that often leave the dragons dismembered, traumatized, and/or dead. Some humans on the station objected, but those who did were quickly and violently silenced.

But, naturally, the humans who objected weren't the only ones who didn't approve of this. The dragons, much to the shock of NO ONE EVER, wouldn't go quietly to this grisly fate. After quite a few escape attempts, one of which ended in the dragon opening an airlock and spacing itself along with a slew of researchers, the humans came up with a fairly reliable system to ensure the dragons didn't escape.

**THE HUMAN'S SET UP**

The humans outfit each dragon they kidnap with metal clamps custom-tailored to fit each dragon; one on each foot, one on each wing, and one around the neck. The inside of these clamps has a texture meant to maximize friction with a dragon's scales to ensure the dragons can't get them off while also allowing them to not be too tight to restrict blood flow. These clamps can be hooked up to 'dock' ports, allowing the humans to secure a dragon to an operating table without first removing the clamps. These ports can also serve as a valve that, when hooked up to a cord, can accept various substances into compartments within the clamps, where they can then be injected into the dragon via needles in the clamps. The clamp around the neck also features components that allow it to monitor a dragon's vitals in addition to tracking the dragon's location, letting the humans know if a dragon isn't where they're supposed to be. The collar doesn't have a visible antenna, by the way.

When not brought out for testing purposes, each dragon is kept in a sound-proofed and airtight chamber with no gravity or light to see by, the goal being sensory deprivation. The dragons are kept suspended in the center of the chamber via cords that hook up to the clamps. These cords also supply the clamps with a sedative drug that helps ensure the dragon doesn't try to escape. Moreover, each chamber has an independent life support system, letting the humans do some tests such as the effects of pressure, temperature, and certain gasses without taking the dragons out of the chamber.

Should a dragon shrug off the sedative while in the chamber, they simply cut the oxygen content of the room down to levels that render them unconscious while they up the dosage. When they are sure the dragon won't be shrugging off the sedative anytime soon, they return oxygen in the chamber to normal levels.

And now, my question. **What flaws might this system have, and how might a dragon escapee exploit them?** I'm basically asking what kind of circumstances would allow a particularly clever or really lucky dragon to get out of the cell and evade recapture. Note that the station is very large and old, which means that there are decrepit sections a dragon that has escaped its cell and gotten its neck clamp off could hide in.

**EDITS:**

The dragon telepaths are limited SOLELY to reading surface thoughts from other dragons and emotions from humans. No Xavier-level telepaths or mind-slavers, unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like you're asking about the actions of a specific individual in a scenario you've constructed for them. Such story based questions are off topic on this site.

Comment: @sphennings I'm not asking about the actions of a specific individual. I'm asking if there are any flaws in the system the humans have set up.

Comment: It seems like you're wanting to write a dragon escape scene. Escape scenes tend to not be a fact of the world but cool events that play out in an already constructed world. As such it's not really a good fit for this site.

Comment: It is difficult to answers questions like this.  It is very similar to questions we get involving how to defeat an impossible to defeat super villain.  It all boils down to what flaws or limitations you want to introduce becomes the answer.  At which point it becomes opinion based or story based. For example an incompetent guard or expired sedatives are not world building but plot devices.

Comment: You are the author. We can't tell you if in your world dragon teeth are made out of plutonium and their secret weapon is the irradiation they can project by dislocating their jaws and bringing the molars into contact like the demon core...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You forgot the muzzle.

Like most human plans, you addressed all the minor security issues and missed the single most significant flaw: dragons can breath all sorts of stuff from thier mouth.  Sedation does not work the same on everyone and the same will be true of dragons.  Some dragons will wake up while they are still out of thier cages and have no problems filling a room full of researchers with ice, fire, poison, etc.

Once the researchers are all dead, the dragon may have enough time to full shrug off the sedatives and pull itself free of the restraints: even if it means ripping out a few scales in the process.

### What if you did muzzle them?

This makes surviving using its breath weapon much harder, but does not necessarily mean that the dragon will not use it anyway.  After a combination of torture and drugs, a dragon may very well choose to go full blast not just blowing it's own head off, but incinerating everyone in the room with it too.  While that particular dragon may not live, he may in the process take out the whole research team responsible for maintaining the prison cells. So, any dragon lucky enough to have the air on and the drugs off at that moment in time will slowly recover thier full faculties and eventually become cognoscente enough to rip themselves out of thier shackles and claw thier way out of thier prisons.

Comment: Yes, they DID forget the muzzle, partially because they have a concerning degree of confidence that their sedative will work every time, and partially because a muzzle may cause a dragon to suffocate. However, you should also note that being overconfident and being an idiot can be completely independent of each other; they always keep a mecha close by when the dragon comes out of the cell. Plus, pulling themselves free of the shackles entails a lot more than just ripping out a few scales: slipping out requires full-on degloving.

Comment: That being said, the above plan still works. It just entails a dragon pretending to be under the sedative while he subtly works his way out of the restraints, then bolting before the humans notice he's slipped his restraints.

Comment: @Brinstar77 As for the restraints, some dragons may be able to dislocate talons the way some humans can thier thumbs; so, while the shackles may work on most dragons, there is always the risk of running into that one dragon that is an escape artist.

Answer (score 3):

Two ideas for you my friend. (**Edit:** Three ideas)

**1. Nightmare Zone**

[image]

Super smart Telepathic Dragon in a sensory deprivation tank? Of course that dragon's psychic power goes into overdrive.

When one sense is removed the other five rise to compensate. When five physical senses are removed the sixth psychic sense rises to compensate.

If the dragon was conscious it would turn all lesser life in a mile radius into willing thralls. Slave, open the restraints. And then they leave and fly away.

Unfortunately the dragon is doped up to its eyeballs. The psychic emanations come not from the Dragon's conscious mind but from its drug-induced nightmares.

The research lab becomes a Lovecraftian hellscape. No human in a mile radius can sleep. Then the walls start melting. Then they scratch out their own eyeballs. It's very scary. No one knows it's the dragon.

This perplexes people who monitor the lab remotely. Nothing strange appears on sensors. You have to be physically in the lab to be effected.

Eventually, by sheer accident, one of the demented people releases a dragon. That dragon releases the others. Problem solved.

**2. Traitor**

[image]

No matter what the restraints are, they can be overcome by simply asking nicely. And also offering a sizeable reward. Dragons are known for their hoards. If you help me escape you can choose one item from my hoard. And I will pretend I didn't see you take it.

Maybe the Dragon has gold and jewels in its hoard. They love that stuff.

Maybe the dragon has Maidens? Dragons love maidens. Maybe some of the maidens look like Geena Davis from The Fly?

In case you are worried, the dragon does not eat the maidens. The dragon simply collects the maidens like you would collect songbirds.

Maybe you don't like maidens? Well good news -- the Dragon is very bad at telling one human from another. So you might get lucky and find a maiden who looks exactly like Jeff Goldblum (also from The Fly).

**3. Numerous Breath Weapons**

Some dragons breath fire. Some breath clouds of steam. Some breath wasps. The dragon was observed to breath first and fitted with a fireproof muzzle. But the muzzle was not wasps-proof. The dragon excaped by breathing wasps instead of fire.

Comment: Number 1: Their telepathy does not work like that: it is limited purely to reading surface thoughts.

Comment: Number 2: The humans aren't really vulnerable to greed, and the dragons have nothing to offer them. However, there is another emotion that might lead to a human turning Traitor: empathy. A human who doesn't want the dragon to suffer might release the dragon when nobody is looking, and maybe even give the dragon a relatively easy-to-understand map to the nearest way off the station.

Comment: Number 3: There are no dragons who can breathe wasps, but there are dragons who can breathe supercold gas, and heat resistant isn't necessarily the same as cold-resistant.

Comment: @Brinstar77 Number 2: Okay then that's good. A maverick scientist injects himself with his experimental genetic goopy dragon DNA goo before it is ready. It kinda works. He is the first human to get (limited) telepathy to read the dragon's mind, and the first one to realise the dragons are intelligent. No one else believes him since the serum ALSO gives him hallucinations. So he has to escape the dragon on his own.

Comment: @Brinstar77 Number 2: Nothing to offer them? Perhaps Maidens shaped like Geena Davis and Jeff Goldblum is a little hard to believe. But I think, being a dragon after all, it should at least be able to offer a collector's edition DVD of Cronenberg's The Fly.

Comment: @Brinstar77 Why no wasps?

Comment: Number 2: The people in charge, along with anyone else who knows ANYTHING about dragon biology, know that these dragons are sentient and intelligent already. But the people in charge don't care and have used extensive propaganda to convince the general populace otherwise, while also forcing the scientist to keep quiet about their discoveries regarding draconic sentience. However, the one maverick scientist you mentioned above MIGHT care. And just like that, you have your dragon sympathizer, in the perfect position to let a dragon escape.

Comment: @Brinstar77 Your story might be more more fun if you make it part of the history of the world rather than the present. If everyone currently knows dragons are sentient, they at some point did not know. Your story begins at that point in time. In fact this maverick scientist is how they found it out. It also provides a way for the reader to learn things as the characters do. You can always switch it up with a 5 year timeskip if you want background information to suddenly become common knowledge. Why five years? Everyone knows that's the incubation period of a dragon egg.

Comment: It already is part of the history. Human scientists, upon first seeing the dragons, realized they were sentient, but the humans in charge made them hide their discovery, much like how during the rise of Nazism, scientists were forced to hide any research that contradicted Hitler's ideas of a 'Master race'. Of course, one scientist decides to resist and releases a dragon.

Answer (score 2):

**(anyone in favor of getting Telepathy?)**

One of these dragons turns out to be a serious Charles Xavier caliber telepath.  It can cause the humans to see things that are not there, and perceive one thing as another.  It is a lot of work for Dragon Xavier to keep this up, but the other dragons bring it home cooked meals and rub its shoulders, and so far so good.

The dragons do not need to escape because the humans have no dragons captive.  They have caught other humans, and mostly their own comrades and co-conspirators in the schemes.  Instead of the grisly dragon torture the humans think they are doing, they are instead giving each other really bad haircuts,  homemade tattoos of childishly drawn pornographic scenes and some fairly creative body piercing.  That part is not much work for Xavier Dragon because it seems these humans were about to do that anyway and a little telepathic encouragement is all that was required.

When Xavier finally wears out, your main human character will realize with a start that his hair (all his hair) is turqoise and in little tufts, and his entire body is one big graphic novel depicting the Xrated trouble he got into at the petting zoo.  And he realizes (because of how the pygmy goats are (lovingly) depicted) that he must have done most of the tattoo himself.  He rages like Dennis Hopper in the movie Speed! But with turquoise hair and sexy goat tats.

The dragons think this is hilarious and cannot wait to try again!  The humans go back to their malicious drawing board for the sequel.

Comment: The downside of this answer is the other dragons end up calling you Professor XXX which is annoying.

Comment: The dragon's telepathy doesn't work like that, unfortunately.

Comment: . . . or maybe Charles Xratedier